# How to cross compile UnixBench with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, cross-compiling

I successfully installed `UnixBench` without `GRAPHIC_TESTS` into iMX6 Yocto. [Previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510787/how-to-cross-compile-perl-modules)

When i trying to enable `GRAPHIC_TESTS`, i got this error:

```
fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
```

So i add opengl include path into Makefile like this:

```
CFLAGS = \
 -I/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include \
 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9
```

freescale iMX6 yocto looks like does not support OpenGL. so changed this:

```
# GL_LIBS = -lGL -lXext -lX11
# to this ↓ 
GL_LIBS = -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL -lXext -lX11
```

And changed source code:

```
//#include <GL/gl.h>
//#include <GL/glx.h>
// to this ↓
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

Then i got a new error:

```
    src/ubgears.c: In function 'gear':
src/ubgears.c:163:17: error: 'GL_FLAT' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
                 ^
src/ubgears.c:163:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/ubgears.c:168:12: error: 'GL_QUAD_STRIP' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            ^
src/ubgears.c:182:12: error: 'GL_QUADS' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            ^
src/ubgears.c:267:17: error: 'GL_SMOOTH' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
                 ^
src/ubgears.c: In function 'reshape':
src/ubgears.c:320:17: error: 'GL_PROJECTION' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                 ^
src/ubgears.c:327:17: error: 'GL_MODELVIEW' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                 ^
src/ubgears.c: In function 'init':
src/ubgears.c:341:14: error: 'GL_LIGHT0' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
              ^
src/ubgears.c:341:25: error: 'GL_POSITION' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
                         ^
src/ubgears.c:343:13: error: 'GL_LIGHTING' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
             ^
src/ubgears.c:349:21: error: 'GL_COMPILE' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glNewList(gear1, GL_COMPILE);
                     ^
src/ubgears.c:350:27: error: 'GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
                           ^
src/ubgears.c:366:13: error: 'GL_NORMALIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
             ^
src/ubgears.c: At top level:
src/ubgears.c:378:30: error: unknown type name 'GLXContext'
              Window *winRet, GLXContext *ctxRet)
                              ^
src/ubgears.c: In function 'main':
src/ubgears.c:561:4: error: unknown type name 'GLXContext'
```

this code maybe only use for OpenGL not OpenGLES.

If anyone have idea about this, please share it.

**Update:**

There is `glxgears -info` in Yocto, and i check the source code in [here](https://fossies.org/dox/mesa-demos-8.3.0/glxgears_8c_source.html) . it's written by OpenGL not OpenGL ES! iMX6 is supposed be only support OpenGL ES. How it works?

**Solution:**
It was my mistake. i indicated the wrong OpenGL libs and headers.

```
# GL_LIBS = -lGL -lXext -lX11
# to this ↓ 
GL_LIBS = -lXext -lX11 /work/fsl-release-bsp/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to compile OpenGL code for OpenGL ES platforms; the two are not compatible, so that's not going to work.

Comment: freescale iMX6 GPU only support OpenGL ES, So is there any doc about convert OpenGL to OpenGL ES?

Comment: No doc - it's not a trivial conversion (a lot of functionality in OpenGL simply doesn't exist in OpenGL ES, especially 2.0 onwards which removed the fixed function path). Based on the functions in use it does look like your code is using fixed function logic, so I'd start looking at OpenGL ES 1.1, not 2.0.

Comment: Also, you don't just need to fix the code, your model data might need changing. It looks like you code is using GL_QUADS (and related) which don't exist in GL ES; you'll need to triangulate the models and use GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: Finally i found out the OpenGL lib and compile the source with OpenGL not OpenGL ES. Thanks for answering.